# Java EE persisting images

Tags: java, image, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

My application(s') architecture looks like this. I have a desktop Java application for administering a web store. That includes creating products and uploading images for them to the application server where the products are persisted. I'm using ejbs for this.

That's the first and main problem. How should add/upload the images? A lot of recommendations say that you should NOT save images as blobs because that ruins performance, especially when you have a lot of reads such as here. On the other hand, saving to the file system is discouraged because that ruins modularity and EJB's should not do that. These are very opposing recommendations. On the other hand, if I want to save multiple files (`byte[]`) for one `Product` class, I'm not sure how to to that. A List does not seem right, and how would a `byte[][]` be persisted? All the examples online are for one file/image only.

This question tags along another. Depending on the way the images are saved, how should I then fetch them in the web application? When sending them they should be "cached" somehow, so they can be hotlinked or if they are a thumbnailed when a user clicks on it.

Comment: I would go with uploading the files seperately to the server and only persisting the path to file. I have never seen a picture being uploaded as blob.

Comment: Ok, great. But how will I then access them from the web application? I need a URL to them. How to make them public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering the part about fetching the image stored in web server through a web application.

Implement a filter class in web application which will **map url to the actual image** stored in either file system or blob. The url should contain a reference to the image id and the  filter should know how to retrieve the actual image using the image id. Also, if you keep this path consistent and have a proper expires header, the browser will take care of caching the image.

I would personally prefer to store images in the file system rather than database as a database is not optimized for this kind of stuff.
Please refer to [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay) for deciding whether to store images as blobs or files.

Comment: Thankyou. I'm using JSF so I don't really need filters I guess.
I made an alternate docroot on the server, mapping it to a directory where the images will be stored, making it easily available. That way the images have constant paths.

Answer (score 1):

try to keep things simple and pragmatic ;-)

I agree with not saving the pictures in a BLOB just upload them to a directory, BUT manage them in a database.

For example: Upload the image to the server, generate a unique id for its filename and save it. Then add the ID to a images database and link it to the article database. So you're able to manage a 1..N relation for multiple images on one product that are easy to fetch and implement. Also later management for deleting an article supports easier deletion, updating etc. of the images.

Also, try to not use a filename / link that represents the product in any way. You might want to have the same image for multiple articles / products.